# Cannot delete files on SDcard

Tags: java, android, delete-file, android-sdcard

I am trying to delete some files on the SD card , but i ran out of ideas..

I tried `File.delete()` method, then I have tried  `file.getCanonicalFile().delete()`
and many more ..
My application can just delete files on the device storage .
I have got the permissions defined in the Manifest file that is required like below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I am requesting for permission in the code also:

```
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.read_storage_message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MainActivity.READ_STORAGE_PERMISSION_ID);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                AppKiller.kill();

                            }
                        }
                ).show();
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(R.string.write_storage_message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MainActivity.STORAGE_PERMISSION_ID);
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                AppKiller.kill();

                            }
                        }
                ).show();
    }
}
```

I am using the following method to delete the files, but as i mentioned before, I've used plenty of solutions found in Stack-overflow and others.

```
protected boolean delete(Context context) throws Exception {
        boolean delete = false;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + getName());
        if (file.exists()) {
            delete = file.delete();
            if (!delete) {
                delete = file.getCanonicalFile().delete();
            }
            if (!delete) {
                String deleteCmd = "rm -r " + file.getAbsolutePath();
                Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                runtime.exec(deleteCmd);
            }
        }
        return delete;
    }
```

could it be because i am asking for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions, but in code i am just getting `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` granted and the other is getting ignored from Android(it won't show permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` popup with allow-deny options after I accept the first one) . Isn't it because they have the same permission's level in android ?

what could be wrong ?

Comment: I am using a class to switch between device storage and SDcard, the previous code is just an example of my code, the only thing that changes the path and the file name 
the path returned is : "/storage/6364-3136/..."
the result executing the adb command in code is :" Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied"

Comment: @pskink I used both combination File(path), File(path, filename) and still not deleting !

Comment: The file is on a removable SD card. You will need to use `DocumentFile#delete`.  Answers suggesting `java.io.File#delete` are wrong.

Comment: I have got the following output :
 C:\adb>adb shell ls -l /storage/6364-3136/Image Files/IMG-20180622-WA0016.jpg
    ls: /storage/6364-3136/Image: No such file or directory
    ls: Files/IMG-20180622-WA0016.jpg: No such file or directory

Comment: i use adb shell ls -l /the/path/returned/by/Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() for device storage only not for SDcard and it works fine . the problem when i use the following path "/storage/6364-3136/" which is my SDcard path !

Comment: @JaredRummler any suggestions for a good tutorial about it ? as I saw there is not much about DoumentFile

Comment: @Anas.J have you got your answer? Can you please describe it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you cannot delete files from SD card on modern Android versions anymore using the File class.

Use the Storage Access Framework instead.

Have a look at `Intent.OPEN_DOCUMENT_FILE` and `OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

Comment: Hi, can you please describe more? or any example ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete file from SD Card you can use following code:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/myfile.txt");
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Comment: thanks for taking time and answering my question . I am sorry, but i have kind of the same code in my question but it is not working. I checked the path even hardcoded it sometimes. didn't work also !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete file from SD Card you can use following code:

```
File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

where selectedFilePath is the path of the file you want to delete.

> for example: selectedFilePath =
>   /sdcard/YourDirectory/TestFile.mp3

also you have to give permission if you are using >1.6 SDK

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml file

Hope this may help you

Comment: thanks for taking time and answering my question . I regret to tell you, that i have used this method a lot hopping that it may work, but it doesn't .